# Verify An Ubuntu OS On Bootable DVD

Tags: system-installation

I'm familiar with the verification process to verify the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu OS ISO but is there a way to do the same of a bootable DVD containing the OS that was made from an ISO?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what you are searching for, but you might be interested in using the built-in integrity check feature available from the boot menu of the bootable DVD itself. However if you wish to check its integrity even before using it (right after burning process), the answer from Stormlord is probably one of the best way to go...

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Just wasn't sure where to look.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to check whether the DVD created by the downloaded .iso file is ok.

If this is the case, go to the newly created DVD's root folder and open a terminal there.  Canonical places an **md5sum.txt** file there for this purpose.  Check the DVD by typing:

`md5sum --quiet --check md5sum.txt`

If everything is ok, you will see nothing but the terminal prompt after the check is over.  If even one file is not ok, **md5sum** will show it to you.

Comment: Thank you. I thought possibly there might be a md5sum text file included in the bootable DVD that was made but wasn't certain or where to look. Thanks again, I'll do as you suggest.

Comment: You're welcome.  If the answer worked for you, please mark it as **accepted** if you like.  Thank you!